# Display custom menu in header

Tags: magento, menu

I am new in magento and using magento 2.0.7 version and trying to add custom menu in header. I created a menu with name Horizontal Menus and added item in it from Menus Management in admin panel. Now i am stuck to call this menu in header. I searched around but did not find out the way to do this. Also it tried to do this by static block and added html to it. But i need to make it manageable from Menu Management of admin panel. Can anyone suggest me the way.

Edit:
The code i tried by using static block is

```
  <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('megamenu-horizontal')->toHtml();?>
```

But in static block i can manage it by adding html code but i want it manageable from Menus Management.

Comment: Could you please add some code snippet for basic reference

Comment: I didn't found any code for this. I just created menu from admin panel and want to show in header.